# Get grandchild elements of document in javascript

Tags: javascript, get, element, document, grandchild

How can I get grandchildren div and iframe of a document in javascript ? I have the id of div and name of iframe

Comment: get direct grandchild by `document.getElementById('someid')` if your grandchild has id.

Comment: You can use the `parentNode` of the `parentNode` like this: `document.getElementById('someid').parentNode.parentNode`

Comment: Well, my problem is that although my "div" and "Iframe" have ids, but when I try to retrieve them using document.getElementById I get the error "object is null" so it looks like it can't see it. I need a way to navigate through the children and grandchildren, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: @user3340627 Any feedback for me?

Comment: @ZachSaucier Sorry for my late reply, but I'm unable to test at the moment, as I've moved on in the project. I will give it a try as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

Example:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#iframeId .someSelector");
```

If you have an ID for child you can just use that:

```
document.getElementById("divId");
```

Or you could use a combination of selectors like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#iframeId > .someSelector > *");
```